# How to execute shell commands inside a loop in Grunt?

Tags: node.js, shell, gruntjs, exec

I have an app folder with multiple subfolders. I'm looping through these folders and trying to run a shell command for each folder. This is what i have so far:

```
grunt.registerTask('deploy', function() {

    var done = this.async();
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;

    // Start deployment
    grunt.log.write('Starting deployment...').ok();

    // Read all subdirectories from the app folder
    grunt.file.expand("./app/*").forEach(function (dir) {

        // Get folder name
        var functionName = dir.split('/')[2];

        exec('echo ' + functionName, {
            cwd: dir
        }, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            grunt.log.ok(functionName+' deployed.');
            done();
        });

    });

});
```

What i would expect in my terminal is to print out each folder name, but all i got is the callback in the exec function, like this:

```
Running "deploy" task
Starting deployment...OK
>> testA deployed.
>> testB deployed.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the command can be found in the `stdout` variable passed to your callback. It's not automatically printed the terminal.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense, however its still not working properly. If i have 3 folders, sometimes only two of them is processed before the grunt finishes, so something is wrong with the async part too.

Comment: You call `done()` in the command callback, so the task will be considered done after the first one.